# SqlDataAdapter returns unexpected rows in SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

Short description of the situation.

A web application where the user can choose some search criteria, hit the search button, and see the results displayed in a grid.

This application works as expected on our development servers. However, when deployed on the customer's server, the paging of the grid is broken: the first page is correct, but next pages don't return the correct rows. I can only explain what happens with an example:

Suppose page 1 should show results 1-10, page 2 results 11-20, etc.

What happens is something like this: page 1 shows 1-10, page 2 shows 1,2,3,4,**6**, **8**,9,28,29,30 page 3 shows 1,2,3,28,29,36,37,..

So the rows are messed up, and a lot of results are never displayed (replaced by result from previous page). Also note that the rows are not just off by some number.

After many hours of searching and debugging I can only conclude that the Fill() method of the SqlDataAdapter that's being used returns the wrong results! The adapter uses a SqlCommand, with an SQL query as plain text. I can run this query in SQL Server Management Studio, where it returns the correct results, so it really must go wrong inside the .NET framework itself.

I've tried to enable .NET source debugging to step into the Fill method, but I can't get that to work, so basically I'm out of options now..

Any tips/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

< problem is solved, see answer below >

Comment: Are you sure that the table structure is exactly the same as in development environment? I mean primary keys, data types etc.

Comment: We transported the database from the customer to our development environment yesterday, it was just then that we discovered that the application worked correctly on our own server.

Comment: What criteria are the results paged by - could it be a collation/localisation problem, like date time being auto-converted to a different format for instance or strings being case insensitive on one server and not the other? Given the settings on each server it could explain odd results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem. The SQL query implements paging manually (don't ask me why, I didn't write the code, I just have to maintain it ;-) ).
The following statements were used:

```
("DELETE FROM #tmp WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT TOP {0} AccountId FROM #tmp);", request.PageStart)
("SELECT DISTINCT TOP {0} ", request.NumRecords);
```

The #tmp table was created in the previous statement, with a specific ORDER BY clause. Since the #tmp table is already ordered, you'd expect that the delete statement would delete the correct top records. But apparently the order isn't applied correctly anymore when using the SqlDataAdapter in combination with a SQL Server 2012 database. After adding the same order by clause as the query that creates the #tmp table, the problem was solved.
Still one question left: is this a bug or a feature?